# Pasar código de jQuery a js puro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito por favor alguien me pueda ayudar a pasar el siguiente código :

```
$('.menu-btn').click(function(){
 $('.navbar .menu').toggleClass("active");
 $('.menu-btn i').toggleClass("active");
});
```

Soy principiante en js.

Comment: El hecho de que seas principiante no limita poner algo de tu esfuerzo, muestra qué es lo que has intendado y enfoca tu pregunta a dudas relacionadas a tu código. Las preguntas que no demuestran esfuerzo mínimo y solo piden resolver un problema no son bien recibidas. Te invito a revisar [ask] y a hacer el [tour], de paso ganas tu primera medalla.

Comment: Creo que leyendo la documentacion de jQuery podras hacerlo, ya que ahi te explica que es lo que hace y como funciona cada cosa.

Comment: Gracias Ricardo, mi error ha sido no mostrar el código con el cual he estado intentando ejecutar, para la próxima pregunta ya lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener elementos con el selector, usa [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), jQuery usa un método nativo que recorre todos los elementos con dicho selector: [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), finalmente con [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventListener), puedes escuchar al evento `click`, las funciones de `class` se asocian a [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.menu-btn').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.navbar .menu, menu-btn i').forEach(function(el2) {
      el2.classList.toggle("active");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, con el forEach me ayudaste bastante me faltaba considerar que querySelectorAll genera un nodeList.